# Move zip file from one folder to another with VSCode Terminal

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, command-line, terminal

I want to use my VSCode terminal to move my zip file in my Downloads folder to my C:/Program Files directory. I looked online but couldn't find the command I am supposed to be using. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

I tried this: `mv Downloads/jdk-11.0.2 ../../C:/Program Files` but I get an error that says `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello the problem is that your path contains a white space and that is seen as a new argument.

You can either enclose the path with double quotes:

`mv "Downloads/jdk-11.0.2 ../../C:/Program Files"`

or escape the white space with `^`

`mv Downloads/jdk-11.0.2 ../../C:/Program^ Files`

Source: [Tutorial about it](https://www.howtogeek.com/694949/how-to-escape-spaces-in-file-paths-on-the-windows-command-line/)